# Post Facebook graph story with link but without deep-linking

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

If a user were to post a URL to their Facebook feed though the Facebook website, FB will scrape the page and construct an Open Graph story using the og: metadata on the page, giving a nice summary box for the link.

I can post the same thing on their behalf from an iOS app by adding the "link" parameter - however this now opens in my app instead of the browser. If I instead include the URL in the "message" parameter, then FB does not parse and generate an object for it.

How can I post a URL as an Open Graph object from my app *without* it deep-linking?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in the Facebook app settings to toggle deep-linking on iOS. However, this is all-or-nothing.